# Why are static analyzer issues not failing my CI build?

Tags: xcode, travis-ci, static-analysis, xcodebuild

I have a project [on GitHub](https://github.com/abbeycode/UnrarKit) with an automated build [on Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org/abbeycode/UnrarKit). The current revision of my code (`buildfix` branch, commit `3ebc41a8b4738bce926b39cc3869c6dce8bed9bc`) is succeeding, even though I have one static analyzer issue. This is the `xcodebuild` command:

```
xcodebuild -workspace UnrarKit.xcworkspace -scheme UnrarKit -sdk macosx -configuration Release analyze test
```

I also have "Treat Warnings as Errors" set to YES for the whole project (for Release builds). I get this output from `xcodebuild`:

> ```
> The following commands produced analyzer issues:
>   Analyze Classes/URKArchive.mm
> (1 command with analyzer issues)
> ```

I reproduced this with `xcodebuild` in my local Terminal with the same result.

Why does `xcodebuild` still return `0` and allow my build to succeed? Why allow `xcodebuild` to analyze in the first place if the results can't be used? If it's a bug, I'll file it with Apple, but at the moment I'm open to the possibility I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that it's the expected behavior to return 0. After all the last log is ** ANALYZE SUCCEEDED **.
You can get html reports with

```
xcodebuild -workspace UnrarKit.xcworkspace -scheme UnrarKit -sdk macosx -configuration Release analyze test CLANG_ANALYZER_OUTPUT=html CLANG_ANALYZER_OUTPUT_DIR=analyzer
find analyzer -name *.html
```

I'm also trying to find a way to make it return something else than 0, the only thing I came up with is:

```
xcodebuild analyze ... && [[ -z `find analyzer -name "*.html"` ]]
```

Comment: When we use ```[[ -z `find analyzer -name "*.html"` ]]``` in `.gitlab-ci.yml` it's giving syntax error. _"Error: jobs:..:script config should be an array of strings or a string"_ What should be the suitable  solution for Gitlab CI/CD?

Comment: For Gitlab CI/CD, I found a solution and will post as an answer below.

Answer (score 2):

For Gitlab CI/CD, I made the similar functionality with below bash statement:

```
echo "failOnWarnings" | exit `find analyzer -name "*.html" -print -quit | wc -l`
```

If there is any html file in **analyzer** folder exit code will be 1 (that means failure), else exit code will be 0 (that means success).

It tested on GitLab MacOS runner 11.11.3 (darwin/amd64) and works. \o/